# does "STDIN" written in <> effect behaviour of perl program?

Tags: perl

I've two perl scripts, both of them wait for user to enter some input as below,

Does both of them are same ?
Does "STDIN" written in <> are just to for user-readability of code ?
If not please tell me the differences.

```
a) $in = <STDIN>;

b) $in = <>;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The form `<FILEHANDLE>` will only read from `FILEHANDLE`.

The form `<>` will read from `STDIN` if `@ARGV` is empty; or from all the files whose names are still in `@ARGV` which contains the command line arguments passed to the program.

Comment: I didn't know that part about `@ARGV` +1

Comment: @JasonSperske You mean you've never written `while (<>) {...}` in a script that takes filename arguments, so that it would process the files?

Comment: @Mortiz Thanks for your answer. My question was regarding differences between both the `script a` and `script b` is mentioned in my question.

Comment: @aravindramesh I told you what the difference between the two syntaxes is. It's way more than just eye candy. With `<STDIN>` you explicitely prevent Perl from reading from the files named in `@ARGV`.

Comment: @texasbruce yes of course, I've corrected the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

`<>` is shorthand for `<ARGV>`. And [`ARGV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#ARGV) is a special filehandle that either opens and iterates through all of the filenames specified in `@ARGV` (the command-line arguments) or gets aliased to `STDIN` (when `@ARGV` is empty).

Comment: no, it doesn't get aliased to `STDIN`, it is still `ARGV`, which reads from `-` aka STDIN when `@ARGV` is empty.  the difference is that when you reach eof and read another time, it will check `@ARGV` again, opening the file from there if one was set and defaulting again to `-` if not.

Answer (score 0):

More information about `<>` you can get from [perlop, section about I/O Operators](http://p3rl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators)

Comment: I found `<>` 14 times in perlfunc - what section do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, i mean perlop, section about I/O operators. I will correct my answer, thank.